# Java - Given a String, how to order all its chars alphabetically to produce a new String?

Tags: java, string, performance, algorithm, sorting

For example, if I start with the string "dcab" I want a function that takes that string and produces the string "abcd" from it. Likewise "cat" should produce "act". I'm trying to think of an efficient way to do this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Transform string into character array
2. Use [`Arrays.sort(char[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char[]%29)
3. Transform sorted character array into new string

Not too sure about efficiency, but this is probably the simplest implementation.

Answer (score 12):

The fastest way to do this (especially if you have a fairly small alphabet to work with, and not all of Unicode) would be to do a [Pigeonhole sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort).

Note that for a very large string, this will be much faster than `Arrays.sort()`, because `Arrays.sort()` is (IIRC) a merge sort, so it runs in `O(n log n)` time, while Pigeonhole sort runs in `O(n + N)` time, where `n` is the number of elements and `N` is the number of alphabet elements.

Answer (score 4):

```
char[] array = str.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(array)
return new String(array);
```

Comment: `Arrays.sort` sorts the array inplace and returns void. This code will not work.